# How can i understand Thread.interrupt()?

Tags: java, multithreading, jvm

There are two code block in java.

Block One:

```
@Test
public void test1() {

    System.out.println("interrupt:" + Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted());
    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    System.out.println("interrupt:" + Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted());

}
```

Output:

```
interrupt:false
interrupt:true
```

Block Two:

```
@Test
public void test2() throws InterruptedException {
    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("running...");
        }
    });

    thread.interrupt();

    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);

    System.out.println("interrupt:" + thread.isInterrupted());

    thread.start();

    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);

    System.out.println("interrupt:" + thread.isInterrupted());

}
```

Output:

```
interrupt:false
running...
interrupt:false
```

So, my questions:

1. Why block one print `interrupt:true` after invoke `interrupt()` but block two not?
2. What will JVM do after invoke interrupt()?

Thanks!

PS:Block Three:

```
@Test
public void test3() {
    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("running...");
        }
    });

    thread.interrupt();

    System.out.println("interrupt:" + thread.isInterrupted());

    // thread.start();
    //
    // thread.interrupt();
    //
    //
    // System.out.println("interrupt:" + thread.isInterrupted());

}
```

Also output : `interrupt:false`

Comment: Interrupting a thread before it is started is a no-op.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- In block 1, you interrupt yourself, this "flag" the thread with interrupted flag.
- In block 2, you interrupt other thread (that is not alive -not started-)

try in the run() method add Thread.sleep(5000); and start before interrupt ;-)

[How interrupt works](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt%28%29)

Comment: Edited your answer to include the Java 7 documentation (Java 6 doc doesn't explain what happens when you call interrupt on a thread that is not started).

Comment: @Perception in Java 6 doc explain the same as Java 7, only change css ;-) 
"Interrupting a thread that is not alive need not have any effect."

Answer (score 2):

It's quite easy. Due to the `sleep` documentation:

`InterruptedException - if another thread has interrupted the current thread. The interrupted status of the current thread is cleared when this exception is thrown.`

When you called `interrupt` and the thread was sleeping the exception was thrown and it simply  cleared the `interrupted` flag.

Block three:

Due to the documentation: `Interrupting a thread that is not alive need not have any effect.` So to sum up: if your thread hasn't started yet `interrupt` method may not work.

Comment: What the hell? Why someone -1 me?

Answer (score 1):

In the source code of [java.lang.Thread](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/Thread.java.html), for the `interrupt` method the documentation clearly says:

> Interrupting a thread that is not alive need not have any effect.

```
  888       /**
  889        * Interrupts this thread.
  890        *
  891        * <p> Unless the current thread is interrupting itself, which is
  892        * always permitted, the {@link #checkAccess() checkAccess} method
  893        * of this thread is invoked, which may cause a {@link
  894        * SecurityException} to be thrown.
  895        *
  896        * <p> If this thread is blocked in an invocation of the {@link
  897        * Object#wait() wait()}, {@link Object#wait(long) wait(long)}, or {@link
  898        * Object#wait(long, int) wait(long, int)} methods of the {@link Object}
  899        * class, or of the {@link #join()}, {@link #join(long)}, {@link
  900        * #join(long, int)}, {@link #sleep(long)}, or {@link #sleep(long, int)},
  901        * methods of this class, then its interrupt status will be cleared and it
  902        * will receive an {@link InterruptedException}.
  903        *
  904        * <p> If this thread is blocked in an I/O operation upon an {@link
  905        * java.nio.channels.InterruptibleChannel </code>interruptible
  906        * channel<code>} then the channel will be closed, the thread's interrupt
  907        * status will be set, and the thread will receive a {@link
  908        * java.nio.channels.ClosedByInterruptException}.
  909        *
  910        * <p> If this thread is blocked in a {@link java.nio.channels.Selector}
  911        * then the thread's interrupt status will be set and it will return
  912        * immediately from the selection operation, possibly with a non-zero
  913        * value, just as if the selector's {@link
  914        * java.nio.channels.Selector#wakeup wakeup} method were invoked.
  915        *
  916        * <p> If none of the previous conditions hold then this thread's interrupt
  917        * status will be set. </p>
  918        *
  919        * <p> Interrupting a thread that is not alive need not have any effect.
  920        *
  921        * @throws  SecurityException
  922        *          if the current thread cannot modify this thread
  923        *
  924        * @revised 6.0
  925        * @spec JSR-51
  926        */
  927       public void interrupt() {
  928           if (this != Thread.currentThread())
  929               checkAccess();
  930   
  931           synchronized (blockerLock) {
  932               Interruptible b = blocker;
  933               if (b != null) {
  934                   interrupt0();           // Just to set the interrupt flag
  935                   b.interrupt(this);
  936                   return;
  937               }
  938           }
  939           interrupt0();
  940       }
```